# Changing column titles in csv files using sql workbench

Tags: csv, header, mysql-workbench

i recently imported a csv file into my sql workbench, when i tried to type the column titles in the WHERE statement, i don't see column name suggestions to choose from.

During the import of the csv file to mysql workbench, i did not remove the space in between the words in the column names, could this be as a result of this?